# Is it possible to remove unecessary nested structure in yaml file?

Tags: python, yaml

I need to set a param that is deep inside a yaml object like below:

```yaml
executors:
  hpc01:
    context:
      cp2k:
        charge: 0
```

Is it possible to make it more clear, for example

```yaml
executors: hpc01: context: cp2k: charge: 0
```

I am using `ruamel.yaml` in Python to parse the file and it fails to parse the example. Is there some yaml dialect can support such style, or is there better way to write such configuration in standard yaml spec?

Comment: I don't believe what you suggesting is a correct YAML

Comment: I know that, I just use it as an example to make it easier to understand what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

since all json is valid yaml...

`executors: {"hpc01" : {"context": {"cp2k": {"charge": 0}}}}`

should be valid...

a little proof:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

a = YAML().load('executors: {"hpc01" : {"context": {"cp2k": {"charge": 0}}}}')

b = YAML().load('''executors:
  hpc01:
    context:
      cp2k:
        charge: 0''')
        
if a == b:
    print ("equal")
```

will print: equal.

Comment: Pairing `""`  and `{}` is more annoy than nested.

Comment: @link89 then your answer is: "no, you can't do that"

Answer (score 1):

What you are proposing is invalid YAML, since the colon + space is parsed as a value indicator. Since
YAML can have mappings as keys for other mappings, you would get all kinds of interpretation issues, such as
should

a: b: c

be interpreted as a mapping with key `a: b` and value `c` or as a mapping with key `a` and value `b: c`.

If you want to write everything on one line, and don't want the overhead of YAML's flow-style, I suggest
you use the fact that the value indicator expects a space after the colon and do a little post-processing:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
before: -1
executors:hpc01:context:cp2k:charge: 0
after: 1
"""

COLON = ':'

def unfold_keys(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        replace = []
        for idx, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()):
            if COLON in k:
                for segment in reversed(k.split(COLON)):
                    v = {segment: v}
                replace.append((idx, k, v))
            else:
                unfold_keys(v)
        for idx, oldkey, kv in replace:
            del d[oldkey]
            v = list(kv.values())[0]
            # v.refold = True
            d.insert(idx, list(kv.keys())[0], v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for elem in d:
            unfold_keys
    return d
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = unfold_keys(yaml.load(yaml_str))
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
before: -1
executors:
  hpc01:
    context:
      cp2k:
        charge: 0
after: 1
```

Since ruamel.yaml parses mappings in the default mode to `CommentedMap` instances which have `.insert()` method,
you can actually preserve the position of the "unfolded" key in the mapping.

You can of course use another character (e.g. underscore). You can also reverse the process by uncommenting the line `# v.refold = True` and provide another recursive function that walks over the data and checks on that attribute and does the reverse
of `unfold_keys()`, just before dumping.